# How to make OneToMany annotation in hibernate

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I have a database that, there is relations between some of tables of it,
for example, I have to table Person and Company, and there is a one to many relation between their Id that is build in a table name Person_Company generated by hibernate.
when I use @OnetoMany and @ManytoOne annotations in java,
It make relation between them, but not according to Person_Company table
and I use just Id 's of table
what is correct annotation?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) can help?

Answer (score 1):

You want the association to be mapped using a join table. So the annotation is (drumroll...) [`@JoinTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html). The javadoc has examples, and the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-manytoone) as well.